# How to run a background thread in ruby?

Tags: ruby, multithreading, chat, backgroundworker

I am new to ruby and thought it would be a great idea to rebuild a simple chat program I made in C#.

I am using Ruby 2.0.0 MRI (Matz’s Ruby Implementation).

The problem is I want to have I/O for simple server commands while the server is running. 
This is the server that was taken from the sample. I added the commands method that uses gets() to get input. I want this method to run as a thread in the background, but the thread is blocking the other thread.

```
require 'socket'                # Get sockets from stdlib

server = TCPServer.open(2000)   # Socket to listen on port 2000

def commands
    x = 1
    while x == 1
        exitProgram = gets.chomp
        if exitProgram == "exit" || exitProgram == "Exit"
            x = 2
            abort("Exiting the program.")
        end
    end
end

def main
    Thread.start(commands)
    Thread.start(server.accept) 
    loop {                          # Servers run forever

        Thread.start(server.accept) do |client|
        client.puts(Time.now.ctime) # Send the time to the client
        client.puts "Closing the connection. Bye!"
        client.close                # Disconnect from the client
      end
    }
end

main
```

This is the client so far.

```
require 'socket'      # Sockets are in standard library

hostname = 'localhost'
port = 2000

s = TCPSocket.open(hostname, port)

while line = s.gets   # Read lines from the socket
  puts line.chop      # And print with platform line terminator
end
s.close               # Close the socket when done
gets.chomp
```

Comment: Are you in MRI Ruby, or JRuby?  Is this in Rails?  These have implications for threading.  I don't believe MRI has native threads.

Comment: I'm pretty sure MRI still has the big fat "global interpreter lock"; meaning that you won't get true concurrency.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Interpreter_Lock

Comment: Thanks then, I guess I will be switching to another ruby, unless there is a non-blocking version of gets()?

Comment: JRuby has real threads.  It might work for you, but has horrible startup time.  (I de-jruby-ed more than one project just for this reason).  If you're running in Rails be careful because a lot of rails isn't thread safe.

Comment: Thanks! I might just do JRuby since I am not really making a web project that could use Rails.

Comment: You don't need JRuby. MRI is fine for chat server. GIL doesn't prevent multi-connections. For instance, nodejs is single threaded but can take highly concurrent requests. You don't have to write thread manually, [eventmachine](https://github.com/eventmachine/eventmachine) is designed for this. There is an EchoServer example on that page.

Comment: The GIL has nothing to do with this @seand. GIL prevents only "true" multithreading i.e. different threads using different cores in parallel. MRI's threads still behave like you would expect in terms of concurrency, they just don't come with the speed boost you would expect from true threading. For something like a simple chat client, that's no big deal.

Comment: I agree, eventmachine will allow a single thread to service multiple connection and is probably the best solution.  However the original poster needs to reimplement his app.

Comment: @Max if the reading "thread" is blocked inside 'gets' would the other thread be able to move?  The gets blocking is most likely inside the kernel.

Comment: @seand see my answer. Nothing is blocking here, `Thread.start` was just being called incorrectly.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Read the documentation for [`Thread.new`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Thread.html#method-c-new) (which is the same as `Thread.start` here)

`Thread.start(commands)` runs the `commands` method and passes its return value to a thread (which then does nothing). It's blocking because you aren't starting any threads when `gets` is called. You want

```
Thread.start { commands }
```

Here's a similar demo script that works just like you would expect

```
def commands
  while gets.strip !~ /^exit$/i
    puts "Invalid command"
  end
  abort "Exiting the program"
end

Thread.start { commands }

loop do
  puts "Type exit:"
  sleep 2
end
```