# Create a background task that is always running

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, telegram-bot, rails-activejob

I have a telegram bot made only in ruby , to execute the bot I have a binary file that run my ruby files. The most important part is listen for new messages from user.

```
Telegram::Bot::Client.run(token) do |bot|
 bot.listen do |message|
 call other methods here
```

But now I want to move from this plain ruby project , for a rails app because I want to start developing more complex features.
So how can I make a task that is always running this listener? I read a little about ActiveJob and Sidekiq, but I don't know how/if is possible to achieve this.

Thanks.

Comment: ActiveJob and Sidekiq are more for executing background jobs (async batch processing). Start with something simple as using a new [Thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25130822/how-to-run-a-background-thread-in-ruby).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ActiveJob and Sidekiq are not what you need. Those are to perform finite jobs in the background. You need some kind of a daemon that starts independently of Rails app. 
Take a look at this https://github.com/thuehlinger/daemons

Answer (score 0):

I think a [Rake Task](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#custom-rake-tasks) would be perfect for this. No additional gems, you only have to set it's running schedules on your server.

In my current situation, I wanted to run a process that would automatically mark records that are more than 48 hours old as `declined`.

So I created a `.rake` file inside the `bin/tasks/` directory, `decline_stale_records.rake`.

Inside the file code kinda looks like this:

```
desc 'Decline stale records'
task decline_stale_records: :environment do
  stale_records = Records.where('created_at >= ?', 48.hours.ago).where.not(approval_status: 'declined')
  stale_records.update_all(approval_status: 'declined')
end
```

In Heroku you can schedule these files to run at your preferred time, read this [guide](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler#scheduling-jobs).

Comment: link only answers are bad answers. include the relevant information here